# Send pub/sub message from Google Tag Manager server side

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I'm in a project and I ran out of ideas... I have an instance of google tag manager server side running, and I want to send data to my cloud function. I've manage to do it through HTTP request but I would like to use cloud function triggered by pub/sub and how to do it? I need to send a pub/sub message from GTM server. Does anyone did it? Is There any kind of integration that I'm not aware?

Any input on that matter is much appreciated!

Comment: Lukas Oldenburg has a fairly extensive article on this on his (much recommended) blog: https://lukas-oldenburg.medium.com/use-google-tag-manager-server-side-for-visitor-stitching-by-querying-a-gcp-database-in-real-time-644001068a1c

Comment: Adding additional documentation that could help you: https://code.markedmondson.me/gtm-serverside-webhooks/ and https://www.roelpeters.be/web-scraping-with-google-cloud-functions-pub-sub-dataflow-bigquery/
Google documentation regarding cloud functions and pub/sub:https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't currently possible. There's no API yet:
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/api

As the other links have stated, you can send your request to a cloud function using HTTP which then sends the Pub-sub message, this means you're paying for the cloud function execution as well as using Pub-sub.

Hopefully, we'll get the API soon that allows us to call Pub-sub directly.